# How to get the pointer to a shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr

I am now hacking an old C code, try to make it more C++/Boost style:

there is a resource allocation function looks like:

```
my_src_type* src;
my_src_create(&src, ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL);
```

i try to wrap src by a shared_ptr:

```
shared_ptr<my_src_type> pSrc;
```

I forgot to mention just now. I need to do this as a loop

```
std::map<string, shared_ptr<my_src_type>  > dict;
my_src_type* raw_ptr;

BOOST_FOREACH(std::string topic, all_topics)
{
    my_src_create(&raw_ptr, ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL);
    boost::shared_ptr<my_src_type> pSrc(raw_ptr);
    dict[topic] = pSrc;
}
```

Can I do it like this?

Comment: I'm surprised nobody mentioned the deleter feature of boost::shared_ptr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Basically, you have to do it the old C way and then convert the result to a `shared_pointer` somehow.

You can do it by simply initializing the shared_pointer

```
my_src_type* pSrc;
my_src_create(&src, ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL);
shared_ptr<my_src_type> sp(pSrc);
```

but beware, this will fail if the `my_src_create` function can return an already existing object. Also, if there is a `my_src_destroy` function, it won't be called.

IMHO the cleanest way is to wrap your structure in a C++ class:

```
class MySrc {
  my_src_type* pSrc;
public:
  MySrc(...) { my_src_create(&pSrc, ...); }
  ~MySrc() { my_src_destroy(&pSrc); }
private:
  MySrc(const MySrc&);
  void operator=(const MySrc&); // disallow copying
};
```

and then use shared pointer for `MySrc` the ususal way.

Comment: In the first block, the shared pointer constructor that takes a raw pointer is explicit, so you have to use explicit initialization: `shared_ptr<my_src_type> sp(pSrc);` instead of `shared_ptr<my_src_type> sp=pSrc;` (also `shared_ptr` is misspelled)

Comment: In your second snippet, you should either make the class non-copyable, or override the default copy constructor and assignment operator to perform a deep-copy.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas, @Emile Cormier: Thanks, reflected your objections in an edit.

Answer (score 8):

### Using `shared_ptr` on C-style resources

With `boost::shared_ptr`, you can pass a function pointer to a "deleter" that will be called automatically when the reference count reaches zero. This feature allows shared_ptr to be used to manage resources returned by legacy C APIs.

Consider leaving your legacy `my_src_create` intact, and provide a new "factory" function that returns a `shared_ptr`:

```
void my_src_deleter(my_src_type* raw_ptr)
{
    my_src_destroy(raw_ptr);
}

typedef boost::shared_ptr<my_src_type> my_src_shared_ptr;

my_src_shared_ptr create_my_src(...)
{
    my_src_type* raw_ptr;
    my_src_create(&raw_ptr, ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL);
    return my_src_shared_ptr(raw_ptr, &my_src_deleter);
}

std::map<string, my_src_shared_ptr> dict;

BOOST_FOREACH(std::string topic, all_topics)
{
    dict[topic] = create_my_src(ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL);
}
```

### Wrapping Legacy C Struct/Functions in a Class

Alternatively, (as jpalecek suggested) you can wrap `my_src` in a class. Creation and destruction of legacy `my_src` objects is handled in the constructor and destructor. If you're going to do this, you should think about whether or not you want your `MySrc` class to be copyable. If `MySrc` is heavyweight or expensive to create, you'll probably want to make it non-copyable and consider using `shared_ptr<MySrc>` if there is going to be shared ownership of `MySrc`:

```
class MySrc
{
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<MySrc> Ptr;
    MySrc(...) { my_src_create(&src_, ...); }
    ~MySrc() { my_src_destroy(&src_); }
    // Other member functions that uses my_src legacy functions

private:
    my_src_type* src_;
    // Make copy-constructor and assignment private to disallow copies
    MySrc(const MySrc& rhs) {}
    MySrc& operator=(const MySrc& rhs) {return *this;}
};

std::map<string, MySrc::Ptr> dict;

BOOST_FOREACH(std::string topic, all_topics)
{
    dict[topic] = MySrc::Ptr(
        new MySrc(ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL) );
}
```

Note that you can also use the `MySrc` class to wrap legacy functions that operate on my_src instances.

If you want `MySrc` to be copyable, then make sure to implement the copy-constructor and assignment operator so that a deep-copy is performed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that your questions makes much sense. If `my_src_create` is being reworked, then pass a reference to the shared pointer, or return a shared pointer instead. If you are not reworking that method then you cannot really do it. I recommend to use a raw pointer for creation and then wrap it into a shared pointer:

```
shared_ptr<my_src_type> src;
{
   my_src_type* raw_src;
   my_src_create(&raw_src, ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL);
   src.reset( raw_src ); // hand ownership to shared_ptr
}
```

Acquiring the pointer inside the shared pointer and modifying it would break the shared pointer invariants: you would be changing the pointer but not updating the share count.

Answer (score 0):

Are you also reworking `my_src_create()`?

Given the name of the function, I would return a boost::shared_ptr rather than passing in a pre-constructed one as that is a lot clearer and cleaner IMHO. Unless the function is also returning some sort of fail/success code, but that would be better dealt by throwing an exception.

If you desperately want to pass in an empty shared_ptr, you can pass it in by non-const reference and use `shared_ptr::reset()` inside `my_src_create` to assign it a new value.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do it "the old way" and then assign that `src` pointer to shared_ptr using [reset()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#reset) or [make_shared()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/smart_ptr/make_shared.html#functions).

Answer (score 0):

I would use this code to solve your problem:

```
my_src_type* src;
my_src_create(&src, ctx, topic, handle_src_event, NULL, NULL);
boost::shared_ptr<my_src_type> pSrc(src);
```

From that point on `pSrc` would manage the allocated memory pointed by `my_src_type* src`.

EDIT: removing an erronous part of my answer.

Comment: The second version is not valid: `pSrc.get()` returns a copy of the pointer, not the actual pointer. Modifying that would have no effect inside the shared pointer

Comment: Yeah, I know. Just got it top of my head without checking. Too early in these parts of the world :) I edited it out.